# For a php include does the file that contains the include need the extension .php?

Tags: php, html, include

I have been trying to learn how to do a php include for an html website. The way I have been doing it has been typing the code for my header, navbar, and footer in php documents and then typing:

```
<?php
    include("header.php")
?>
<?php
    include("navbar.php")
?>
```

in the html file that I wish to include those documents (about.html) and so on. This has not been working for me even when testing with MAMP. Is there a better way to do this? I have heard that the file extension for the file that contains the include needs to be php. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: you need to instruct your system to treat `.html` files as PHP or rename it to `.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This has not been working for me even when testing with MAMP. Is there a better way to do this?

You can include it by echoing out the HTML code in `header.php` and `footer.php`. Directly renaming the `.html` file to `.php` will not work.

> I have heard that the file extension for the file that contains the include needs to be php.

Your file must be PHP, else you cannot `include` it. However, you can instruct the system to treat `.html` files as `.php` files using `.htaccess`. (Thanks @Fred -ii- for pointing out)

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: *"This is true, your extension must be .php, else you cannot include it."* - Not entirely true. OP can use `.html` just as long as they instruct their system to treat `.html` files as PHP; it can be done.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I run `.html` - `.shtml` files on a few servers that run PHP directives with no problem. Edit: You deleted your comment that I answered this with ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Updated post to make it clearer, thanks for pointing out :)